# Linq grouping based on requirements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sales data table that consists of individual item sales, multiple rows make up a single bill(BillID) in the system. The data looks like this:

CompanyID | StoreID |BillItemID| BillID | DateKey | Description | a bunch of other columns for amount sold and taxes etc.

All that matters is really the BillID, I need to find bills that contain both the items that are included in the linq statement where clause.

Here is my current linq statement

```
FactSales
    .Where(c => c.CompanyID == 433)
    .Where(c => c.StoreID == 360)
    .Where(c => c.Description == "2 Piece Combo" || c.Description=="3 Piece Combo")
    .GroupBy(m => new { m.BillID })
```

This selects all sales that were either 2 or 3 piece combos. But the group by doesn't provide the information I need because there are cases where where people buy multiples of the same item so those BillIDs are not representative of bills where both items were sold.

Is this possible with linq?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear; could you provide a sample dataset and output?

Comment: Are the BillID unique numbers?  Or duplicated at different stores?  If unique then why are you filtering on CompanyID and Store ID.  Especially where some companies may have multiple CompanyID numbers but share billing departments.

Comment: BillIDs are not unique they require a storeid and companyid to go with them to be unique but in the case of this query the billID is unique because the other two factors have been set

Comment: I updated the question to show the table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter out the groups that contains **both** items from the `Where`.

There are several ways you could do that.

For instance, counting the distinct items in a group:

```
...
.Where(g => g.Select(c => c.Description).Distinct().Count() == 2)
```

or checking the group content for item existence (duplicating `Where` filter conditions):

```
...
.Where(g => g.Any(c => c.Description == "2 Piece Combo") &&
    g.Any(c => c.Description == "3 Piece Combo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding another condition, with an "&&" where you check for quantity sold is greater than 1. Note, the OR has been grouped together.

```
FactSales
.Where(c => c.CompanyID == 433)
.Where(c => c.StoreID == 360)
.Where(c => (c.Description == "2 Piece Combo" || c.Description=="3 Piece Combo" ) && c.purchaseQuantity > 1)
.GroupBy(m => new { m.BillID })
```